# Regular expression to match a list of floats

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a RegEx which allows following inputs:

100,120

10.50,100

129,10.6

1.1,2.4

And rejects any other inputs. 
Basically a RegEx which validate the numbers(either float or integer) are properly separated by comma(,).

Below is my code for HTML input,

```
<input type='text' className='form-control' pattern='/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/' required/>
```

Trial:

I tried suggested regex `/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/` wrapped inside `\` and attached to `pattern` attribute.

This regex shows invalid input in case of

`1,2`
`1,2,3`
`1.0,1.2`

Comment: Please share with us your attempts to solve this yourself.  We are happy to help, but are less keen on doing free work.

Comment: This will do: ^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$ as pattern.

Comment: @Poul Bak, `"2,5,7,5".match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/);` returns false. Same with `"2"`.

Comment: Can I use the same RegEx in `pattern` attribute of input tag? Or I need to change any characters in to make this RegEx work in Pattern attribute ?

Comment: @Amessihel, of course it returns fals, you can't use the same decimalseparator as you do as separator.

Comment: @Amessihel, so do I. There's only supposed to be two numbers per line.

Comment: @Poul Bak Not sure, OP is talking about lists. But I admit it can be understood this way.

Comment: @PoulBak, It still not working even after adding slash on both side.

Comment: @Code_Art, please edit your question, showing what you try, and what fails.

Comment: @PoulBak, Thank you for the help. Finally i am using array.split(',') and isNan() to validate individual inputs. I have added my own answer. Please refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here should be a working RegExp *(note: non-capturing groups are better than capturing ones for performance)*:

```
/^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:,(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*$/
```

In this regexp:

- `\d+(?:\.\d*)?` = a value an integer part alone, or with a dot with maybe a decimal value
- `\.\d+` = only a decimal part (ie a dot followed by a number)

A float is *either* of the first or the second shape.

Got this, what you want is a list of floats, i.e a single item or one item followed by some items each prefixed by a comma. That's what means `(?:,...)`, where `...` is the first item regexp.

Those tests passed:

```
a-> false
1-> true
2.-> true
.3-> true
1,2-> true
,-> false
1,-> false
,2,-> false
5,6,a-> false
5,a,6-> false
1,.2,3.,4.5-> true
1,.2,.3,4,5,a,6-> false
```

Below, a working snippet to do additional tests:

```js
r = /^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:,(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*$/;
Array(
  "a",
  "1",
  "2.",
  ".3",
  "1,2",
  ",",
  "1,",
  ",2,",
  "5,6,a",
  "5,a,6",
  "1,.2,3.,4.5",
  "1,.2,.3,4,5,a,6").forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e + "-> " + 
              r.test(e));
});
```

If another approach is allowed, why not using `parseFloat` as below:

```js
Array(
      "a",
      "1",
      "2.",
      ".3",
      "1,2",
      ",",
      "1,",
      ",2,",
      "5,6,a",
      "5,a,6",
      "1,.2,3.,4.5",
      "1,.2,.3,4,5,a,6").forEach(function(e) {
      console.log(e + "-> " + 
                  areThoseCommaSeparatedFloats(e));
    });

function areThoseCommaSeparatedFloats(line) {
  try {
    line.split(",").forEach(function(v) {
      // If the value is not a float
      // (in which case parseFloat return NaN)
      // throw an exception
      if (isNaN(parseFloat(v))) throw {};
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // A not-a-number value was found
    return false;
  }
  // All the values are numbers
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Very nice.`(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

Comment: @sln Thanks. Here, does it make a difference if capturing groups are used instead of non-capturing ones?

Comment: `Regex1:   ^(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(,(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    1.35 s,   1345.12 ms,   1345116 µs
Matches per sec:   185,857


Regex2:   ^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:,(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    0.77 s,   769.88 ms,   769880 µs
Matches per sec:   324,725`

Comment: @sln Indeed. I have looked for it, didn't get an answer. Your example is kind of clear. Thank you, I edited the answer.

Comment: @Amessihel, thanks for the solution. Using `parseFloat` is definitely a clean solution. Perhaps, I want to go with `RegEx`. I tried to using same regular expression in my `<input pattern="">` . But it is not working properly.  Gives error for any input.

Comment: @Amessihel, Below is my actual code with react, inside the `render()` method
    `let inputPattern = '^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:,(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*$'; ` 
    `<input name={inputName} type={inputType} className='form-control' placeholder={placeholderText} pattern={inputPattern} required={parameter.required}/>` .  And it shows me bunch of warnings in `console`.


 `Line 42:  Unnecessary escape character: \d  no-useless-escape`
  `Line 42:  Unnecessary escape character: \.  no-useless-escape`
  `Line 42:  Unnecessary escape character: \d  no-useless-escape`

Comment: @Code_Art, 1) remove backslashes (escape characters) 2) surround the pattern with "/" (like the fiddle linked above).

Comment: @Amessihel, thank you so much for the help. I finally end up with the another approach, derived from the `parseFloat`. I started with using `parseFloat`. Perhaps it was converting some invalid inputs to valid inputs. For ex. `3 3` converts to `3`, `4abc.1` converts to `4` etc. Basically `parseFloat` was taking all leading digits if it's `numbers`  and  trimming rest of invalid `space` and `characters`. Which I think kind a vague way to validating input. So, finally using `array.split(',')` and `isNaN()` to validate comma separated combination of decimal and integer numbers.

Comment: I am still adding your response as my `answer`, as  i got lot help from your response.

Answer (score 0):

finally using `array.split(',')` and `isNaN()` to validate comma separated combination of decimal and integer numbers.

`var input = Array.from(input.value.split(',').map(item => item.trim()));`
`input.some(function(i) {return isNan(i)})`